# Prove or disprove whether L is regular by definiton

Tags: formal-languages, regular-languages

Assume L is regular language, define 1 = {:  ∈ , ∉ }, prove or dispute L1 regular or not ?

Comment: What did you try? Where did you get stuck? We're happy to help you understand the concepts but just solving homework-style exercises for you is unlikely to really do that. Try to think about why you can't solve this exercise yourself and ask a question about _that_.

Answer (score 1):

It’s regular.

First we can gain a DFA $M$ which accepts the given language $L$. 
Similarly we have a DFA $\bar M$ which accepts regular language $\bar L$.

Then we can construct a new NFA by adding an $\epsilon$ transition from all the final states in $M$ to $\bar M$’s initial state, which accepts that required language.

Comment: ye when i got 2 different languages its the way to solve it, building 2 separeted DFAs... but can u draw it with steps ? what is the right syntax to prove such question  ?

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand your question. It's basically to connect the two DFA $M$ and $\bar M$ with $\epsilon$ transition.